# toggle flash player release / debug

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I would like to switch from the debug version of the player to the release without having to uninstall. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use firefox you can look at [flash switcher](http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2006/10/flash_switcher_for_firefox.php)

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but flash switcher seams good at toggling between different versions of flash, not release/debug of the same version. I've tried what Shawn says in a comment:
"steps for getting Flash 9 Debug and Flash 10 Debug both working: 
1 Installed this addon
2 Downloaded, installed Flash 10 Debug version
3 Loaded Firefox, saved the Flash 10 version as "Flash 10 Debug"
4 Repeat steps 2, 3 to install Flash 9 debugger the same way"
The problem for me is that I'm trying to have the flashPlayer 10 release and the same version but debug, (...)

Comment: (...)  and the method described just doesn't work as it simple replaces the the current version by the one I install last.

Comment: Flash Switcher is the way to go. You just have to get the .dll files for the debug and release versions.

Comment: Hi Matt W, what do you mean by geting the .dll files? I'm working with mac, so no dll files for me as far as I know. Do you have any suggestion?